# Filter on Array and create new objects

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

Supposing this array:

```
var studends = [("Marc", 404), ("Paul", 450), ("Steve", 490), ("Jar", 500), ("Niels", 520), ("Marco", 540), ("Sacha", 560), ("Mike", 500), ("Ted", 520), ("Ammar", 540), ("Rolph", 560), ("Brian", 590), ("Jeff", 600), ("John", 650), ("Mickael", 890)]
```

How to filter the array and create new objects based on notes segmentation as below :

```
object A +/- 10% of 500
object B +/- 20% of 500
object C +/- 30% of 500
object D +/- 40% of 500
```

Comment: Provide some resultant expected output for this array.

Comment: You surely tried *something.* Don't hesitate to show your attempt!

Comment: try using filter something like `let a = studends.filter { (name, marks) -> Bool in
    // Return true for your requirement
}`

Comment: @jaykaydev: Add that to your question, not to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
struct FirstRange { 
var name: String 
var note: Int 
} 

struct SecondRange { 
var name: String 
var note: Int 
} 

var firstRanges = [FirstRange]() 
var secondRanges = [SecondRange]() 

for studend in studends {
    if studend.1 >= 450 && studend.1 <= 550 {
        let firstRange = FirstRange(name: studend.0, note: studend.1)
        firstRanges.append(firstRange)
    } else if studend.1 >= 400 && studend.1 <= 600 {
        let secondRange = SecondRange(name: studend.0, note: studend.1)
        secondRanges.append(secondRange)
    }
}
```

Based on the notes, how to have highest ranges exclude lowest.